# Convert whole Website in book or pdf format

Tags: 14.04, pdf, wget, websites

Is there any way that I can download whole website content in book/pdf or any printable format.
This is the website which I want to convert to pdf

https://www.netlab.tkk.fi/tutkimus/dtn/theone/javadoc_v141/

to print it in hard form and then read it. I have 14.04 Ubuntu.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322048/how-to-generate-a-pdf-from-javadoc-including-overview-and-package-summaries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded whole website with `wget` then converted it to pdf with Adobe Acrobat, That perfectly worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is going on Fullscreen mode (from the browser menu) and then use Printscreen (next to Delete button) to capture each page. Then organise them as you wish (make chapters linked to the categories/sub-categories) and export it as images or make a pdf.

Comment: those are like 100 pages and its too much time taking.